# information gain calculation for non discrete (continuous) data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, entropy

I'm using the iris data set. this is a non-discrete data set. I'm divided into 3 equal-width method. but after that I do not know what to do. How do I calculate information gain for this dataset ? How to calculate information gain for continuous data ? Please explain this with an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. discretize the attribute (e.g. equal width)
2. map the bins as categoies (e.g. low, medium, high)
3. proceed as with categorial data